# insert data from api to material select input angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an API which return me some data and i try to push this data into mat select input but data in select not display, how i can do it with this api, i just try to make cycle with for but it also not works

```js
 TestArrList:any[]=[];
 data1!:any[];
 
 
  ngOnInit(): void {

    let uri = 'APIURL';
    this.http.get(uri).subscribe((data:any) => {  
      this.TestArrList = data
   
for(var i = 0;i < this.TestArrList.length;i++)
       
   for(var j = 0;j < this.TestArrList[i].Items.length;j++)
      this.data1.push(this.TestArrList[i].Items[j].Name);
    console.log(this.TestArrList);
   return this.data1
      

     }); 
     }
```

```html
<mat-grid-tile [colspan]="fieldColspan">
              <mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="outline" style="width:20vw">
                <mat-label>Location </mat-label>
                <mat-select placeholder ="Select test"  [formControl]="testControl">
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let item of TestArrList"  [value]="item.name">
                    {{item.value}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
            </mat-grid-tile>
```

my result api, i try to get "Value"(value1 for test, value2 for test, value3 for test) from each Items

```
[
    {
        "Items": [
            {
                "Name": "Id",
                "Value": "1"
            },
            {
                "Name": "test",
                "Value": "value1 for test"
            }
        ],
        "Value": null
    },
    {
        "Items": [
            {

                "Name": "Id",
                "Value": "2"
            },      
            {

                "Name": "test",
                "Value": "value2 for test"
            }
        ],
        "Value": null
    },
    {
        "Items": [
            {
                "Name": "Id",
                "Value": "3"
            },
       
            {
                "Name": "test",
                "Value": "value3 for test"
            }
        ],
        "Value": null
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `data` to `TestArrList` but `data` is not in correct format. Instead you can use `reduce`

```js
TestArrList: any[] = [];
data1!: any[];


ngOnInit(): void {

    let uri = 'APIURL';
    this.http.get(uri).subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.TestArrList = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
          acc.push(...curr.Items) // destructuring array
          return acc;
        }, []);

      }
    }
```

```html
<mat-grid-tile [colspan]="fieldColspan">
  <mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="outline" style="width:20vw">
    <mat-label>Location </mat-label>
    <mat-select placeholder="Select test" [formControl]="testControl">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of TestArrList" [value]="item.name">
        {{item.value}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

Comment: what is acc and curr?

Comment: `acc` and `curr` are function argument. `acc` is accumulator which will collect new values and `curr` is current object under iteration

Comment: it also not display item.value in input

Comment: sorry, my fault, it works, but it display values with id in input, i need only value1 for test, value2 for test, value3 for test